# apache mass virtual hosting with suexec and mod_fcgid

Tags: apache2, virtual-hosts, mod-fcgid, suexec

I followed [Falco's tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-apache2-with-mod_fcgid-and-php5-on-ubuntu-11.10) and everything now works as expected for 2 users (e.g. john and alice) with their relevant directories (`/var/www/john` and `/var/ww/alice`).

Now, I want to go to the next level: instead of defining different vhosts at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/<username>` and restarting Apache, I need [dynamically configured mass virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html).
Say, my DNS server has records for: `another.site.example.com`, I want it's home directory to be at `/var/www/another.site/web`.

The problem is all these configuration settings for suexec and mod_fcgid.
I ended to this draft of my `httpd.conf` (or should I create a file like `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mass_virtual` ?):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

#default virtual host
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/root/web/

  <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    SuexecUserGroup web-admin web-admin
    <Directory /var/www/root/web/>
      Options +ExecCGI
      Options -Indexes
      AllowOverride All
      AddHandler fcgid-script .php
      FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/root/php-fcgi-starter .php
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>

  # ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  # CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
  ServerSignature Off

</VirtualHost>

#3rd-level subdomain virtual hosts
<VirtualHost *:80>
  UseCanonicalName Off
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  #problematic email!
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  #is this /var/www/another.site/web or /var/www/www.another.site/web for
  #a request for www.another.site.example.com ?
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-3+/web

  <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    #problematic group and user!
    SuexecUserGroup web1 web1
    <Directory /var/www/*/web/>
      Options +ExecCGI
      Options -Indexes
      AllowOverride All
      AddHandler fcgid-script .php
      FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/*/php-fcgi-starter .php
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>

  # ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  # CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
  ServerSignature Off

</VirtualHost>
```

1. As you can see from the comments I have a problematic `ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com`, a `SuexecUserGroup web1 web1` and a `VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-3+/web` configuration!
2. Moreover, to ensure security I think `IfModule` shouldn't exist-if
   `mod_fcgid` can't load then neither should the server and,
3. instead of `Alow from all`, I think I should have `Deny from all` and open-up a
   php-library directory instead!

Thanks.

Comment: As I said, my intention is a request for **www.another.site.example.com** to be directed to user at **/var/www/another.site/web** but as I've read at [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) at "_Using suEXEC_" we can call suexec without the SuexecUserGroup directive in VirtualHost definitions but with the help of **mod_userdir**! So, what if a request for **www.another.site.example.com** is transformed transparently to **www.example.com/~another.site** with the help of **mod_rewrite** and then use **mod_userdir** to enable suexec??? Any ideas or directives that implement this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, as I have no replies I'll try the half part of my proposed solution(?): **use of mod_userdir to force execution of suexec**

1. Let's create the following /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

   ```
   ##########################################
   ### mod_fcgid configuration directives ###
   ##########################################
   #values should be tuned depending on server memory
   FcgidMaxProcesses 1000
   FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 100
   FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 3
   #see 'export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000' at '/var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/<user>/php-fcgi-starter'
   FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 5000
   FcgidIOTimeout 40
   FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
   FcgidMaxRequestInMem 65536
   FcgidMaxRequestLen 131072
   FcgidOutputBufferSize 65536
   ```
2. Let's create a `mass_virtual` at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

   ```
   #NameVirtualHost *:80

   #default virtual host
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.example.com
     ServerAlias example.com
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/web-admin/web/

     SuexecUserGroup web-admin web-admin
     <Directory /var/www/web-admin/web/>
       Options +ExecCGI
       Options -Indexes
       AllowOverride All
       AddHandler fcgid-script .php
       #FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web-admin/php-fcgi-starter .php
       FcgidWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web-admin/php-fcgi-starter .php
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
     </Directory>

     # ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
     # CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
     ServerSignature Off

   </VirtualHost>

   #3rd-level subdomain virtual hosts
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAlias *.example.com
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
     ##################
     ### solution 1 ###
     ##################
     #mod_vhost_alias directives: needs parameterized SuexecUserGroup(?)
     #UseCanonicalName Off
     #VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-3+/web
     ##################
     ### solution 2 ###
     ##################
     #mod_userdir directives for requests: http://www.example.com/~user
     UserDir disabled root
     UserDir /var/www/*/public_html

     #reduntant if using requests: http://www.example.com/~user
     #SuexecUserGroup web1 web1
     <Directory /var/www/*/public_html>
       Options +ExecCGI
       Options -Indexes
       AllowOverride All
       AddHandler fcgid-script .php
       #move to .htaccess
       #FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/*/php-fcgi-starter .php
       #FcgidWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/*/php-fcgi-starter .php
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
     </Directory>

     # ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
     # CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
     ServerSignature Off

   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   **Problem:** If I uncomment first line I get a warning on server restart that there are no virtual hosts!!
3. Let's create my user bob
4. Let's create a .htaccess at `/var/www/bob/public_html`

   ```
   FcgidWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/bob/php-fcgi-starter .php
   ```
5. Let's hit my browser to `www.example.com/info.php` or `example.com/info.php`

   ```
   web-admin
   ```

   ...as expected but,
6. let's move to `www.example.com/~bob/info.php`

   ```
   ...trying to open info.php!!!
   ```

   let's see errors

   ```
   <root># cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
   [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
   [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
   [notice] Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
   ```

   **As you can see there are NO errors BUT `mod_fcgid` is NOT enabled to run the .php file and apache tries to send it as normal file!!!
   Any ideas how to solve this?**

Comment: DEFINITELY A BUG IN APACHE SEE: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49439 but I need instruction to patch it!!

Comment: have you ever got this run? Im in the same situation trying to restrict users now (also using vhost alias)